# construct 'file' from string to upload using rest api

Tags: reactjs, rest, file-upload, axios

React web app GETs the string content from a REST API. This string content needs to  uploaded to another server using different REST API, which accepts 'file' to upload as 'form-data'. Is there a way to construct in-memory 'File' from string which can be used to upload.

Comment: Using fs would create a real file for you to post.  fs.writeFile('newFile.json', fetchedData, function(err){ if (err} throw err; console.log("saved"})

Comment: @stever, thanks for the update.. I'm new to web app development.. I assume this ok if this javascript code executed on server side.. but using 'fs' to create a file on the client side(from browser) is allowed.?

Comment: I don't think so; have never heard of that.